# Barcode Scanner in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am try to scan barcode using barcode scanner in android mobile using ionic2. I am a new learner of ionic. I tried some code,

home.ts

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
  declare var cordova:any;
  @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  })
  export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  scan() {
  var me = this;
  if (cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner) {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan((imageData) => {
        alert(imageData.text);

    }, (error) => {
        alert("An error happened -> " + error);         
    });
  }

  }
  }
```

home.html

```
  <ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Home
  </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

 <ion-content class="home">
 <button primary (click)="scan()">Scan</button>
 </ion-content>
```

But I got an error is 'Cannot find variable: Cordova'.

I used this plugin -

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/barcode-scanner/

for barcode scanner in ionic2

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Do you still get the error after making the mentioned changes?
Build the application by typing "ionic build android" at the command prompt. Then run the apk file on your phone. It's normal to get this error in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native';
```

after that you can use BarcodeScanner.scan() methods to get the information from a barcode or qr code. Try this code:
home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  click() {
    BarcodeScanner.scan()
      .then((result) => {
        alert(
          "We got a barcode\n" +
          "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
          "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
          "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled
        )
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      })
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h1>Scan</h1>
  <button block (click)="click()" color="primary">Scan</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. After importing - import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native'; also got same error

Comment: Delete the line with declare var cordoba; Use only the object BarcodeScan

Comment: Thank you. Error is solved, but it shows an alert box with "cordova_not_available".

Comment: Are you trying in the browser? You should test on the phone because that is a native function.

Comment: Even remove cordova.plugin when you try to use the scan() method. Use only BarcodeScanner.scan()

Comment: How do I cancel scanner on android?

Answer (score 1):

First do import to your project:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner
```

Component files:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [ BarcodeScanner ]
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,
    public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  scan() {
   this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(barcodeData))
      }, (err) => {
       //error
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.

$ cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner

2.

app.module.ts

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
   @NgModule({

   ......

   providers: [
     BarcodeScanner,
     {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
   ]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

---

scanner.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavParams, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';

 @Component({
    selector: 'page-contact',
    templateUrl: 'contact.html'
 })
export class ContactPage {
    constructor( public nacCtrl: NavController,
    public NavParams: NavParams,
    private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) { }

  takeScan(){
      this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      // Success! Barcode data is here
      alert(barcodeData.text);
      console.log("Barcode Format -> " + barcodeData.format);
      console.log("Cancelled -> " + barcodeData.cancelled);

   }, (err) => {
      // An error occurred
     console.log("An error happened -> " + err);
   });
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the docs you need to do this to use barcode scanner with ionic 2

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native';

BarcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
    // Success! Barcode data is here
  }, (err) => {
   // An error occurred
});
```

After installing, you need to import it in your page from `ionic-native` and then call it to use its functions.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thank you for answering. After importing - import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native'; also got same error

Answer (score 0):

For using Barcode Scanner you have to add

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native';
```

and create a function like this

```
barcode() {
  BarcodeScanner.scan()
  .then((result) => {
     if (!result.cancelled) {
       alert("Success"+result);
     }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    alert(err); 
   })
 }
```

now you can call **barcode()** function anywhere in html to scan

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Add the plugin to your app see below
>
> ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner
>
> 2.import
>
> import { BarcodeScanner } from 'ionic-native';
>
> import * as xml2js from "xml2js";
>
> 3. BarcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
>
> var name,uid;
>
> xml2js.parseString(barcodeData.text,{trim: true}, function (err,
>   result) { debugger;
>
> name=result.PrintLetterBarcodeData.$.name; 
>   uid=result.PrintLetterBarcodeData.$.uid;
>        });
>
> debugger;    this.AdharCardName=name;    this.AdharcardUid=uid;
>   }, (err) => {
>
> });

Answer (score 0):

```
How to create perfect Barcode/QR Scanner. let's do it.
```

firstly,install

1. **ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner**
2. **npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner**
3. **npm install @ionic-native/core --save**
4. **cordova platform update android**

all are done..import **BarcodeScanner** in app.module.ts .like this
  ***import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';***

providers: [
    BarcodeScanner
  ]

after that, we must declare in typescript file which you'll use
    **import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';**

```
scan(){
      this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(barcodeData))  
      }, (err) => {  
       //error 
      });
    }
```

in this case. you can face like this errors,
**ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/index.html):**  or
  ***Unexpected token ) in main.ts ***
don't worry about it..remove ***android/ios plugin*** from command prompt.
and install it.
**cordova platform update android**

I hope good new.
**spy**